# MTM Tests Using a TFS Azure-Based Project

Tags: azure, tfs, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I am waiting for my work to upgrade our TFS version. In the meantime, I made a personal TFS project on my azure account. This allows to "practice" using MTM so that when we upgrade, I can hit the ground running.

I have my personal project in Team Explorer in Visual Studio, linked to TFS, with a Build Definition and a completed Build. I have a Unit Test project in the same sln that references the main project. My test correctly shows in MTM. I also have a Test Controller configured, and Test Agents configured on the Lab Center machines.

I then made a Lab Center environment. We have a virtual machine set up, so I added that one. For "Type" under the Machines tab, I selected Server because I was unsure (not sure if that matters). Nonetheless, I believe it worked because when I hit the verify button, the Test Agent correctly installed on the remote machine. It says Ready. Great!

When I go to run the test, I get the following error: "The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required." All the code does is says "Waiting for Test Controller" before erroring with that message.

I cannot figure out how to troubleshoot this. It is simply a unit test to print "Hey" to the Console. I can supply pictures if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the new task-based build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MTM cannot run automated tests from builds created by the new web-based build system introduced in TFS 2015.

MTM isn't necessary for this, as there are tasks in the new build system for installing/configuring test agents and running tests using those test agents. You just can't manually trigger test execution from MTM.

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't have to be confused anymore.

Comment: Another question for you. When we get upgraded to TFS 2015 (not web-based), I am anticipating the process to be similar to what I was doing for my Azure account in order to run CodedUI automated tests from MTM. Is that a safe assumption?